# Why water flow at high pressure from tap if we close its half portion opening and not maintaing equilibrium of low flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I am having a doubt that when we open a tap and a certain amount of water start coming out supplied by tank . When suppose I close the opening of tap half way so that only half mouth of tap is now opened.

I noticed water cone from a high pressure and velocity! But Why? Actually what I think is that, as space decrease so amount of water should come out should be less that as small amount of water coming out than water rate that tank supplying should decrease no? Let me give You an analogy, suppose a vessel fill with water, 1st I create a small hole in that allow let say 2ml of water, now 2nd i make a even small hole allowing only 1ml of water coming out.

See here water rate decrease as space decrease not pressure increase! According to me pressure should increase when space decrease but rate of water flow remain same (somehow, may be motor or pump pushing water at same pressure no matter how much space is there)as same amount of water HAS to come out to prevent busting of tap so with less space it has to cone at high oressure to maintain a constant rate of flow.

But here in case of tap there no external force pushing water at any constant rate but only tank is giving with the help of opening and an adjustable opening.
So don't you think as i decrease space of opening of tank only a little water should come out at normal pressure not high pressure maintaining an equilibrium and hence the rate of supplying water from tank also decrease.

This figure will help you

[image]

Why not?

[image]

Here why Can't water amount coming out decrease, so that water supplied by tank can also decrease maintain an equilibrium, What is the problem?

**(Here i am depicting tap with supply of water in our hone by tank on house top, diagram is just a simple depiction of it)**

Hope you get, please help i am damn confused.

Edit:- Here what i actually did, I came from outside and want to wash my slippers off mud, but water when i open tap is unable to remove it, so i kept half my finger on its mouth and water start coming with high pressure  as uf like water that has to come from half of close  part now due to being closed is forced to come from that only half ooened part thus coming with high pressure help wash my slipoers off.(like wise we use water to wash cars up with high pressure )

Comment: Good question! I am also confused

Comment: Please share it more and please try to clear it up please, and also please mark my question an uovote if you found it good otherwise it would be close after sone time and i cannt get answer

Comment: @Andrea, please answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you really measure the amount of water per minute, coming out with full and half open tap? it should be less with partly closed tap. so you have really to measure it, not just your impression. Since the tank is usually very large compared to the amount of water you use, the hight of the water in the tank does not vary much. (in most cases it is even refilled from some outer source. So you should explain exactly what you did .

Comment: Look  i have edited it and "it should be less with partly closed tap. so you have really to measure it," as you said  if has to be less from half opened tap than pressure should be same(half space i e half area, half amount of water ) not high, if you want pic i can upload it too.

Comment: please answer... I am veryyyyyy confused